# Question about dimension of solution set and rank

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the followings equation system $$ 2x_1+x_2+x_3=2$$ $$ x_1+x_2=1$$ $$ x_1+x_3=1$$ and the constraints are $x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 0$.
I've calculated that the rank is two, so the dimension of the solution set is $n-2=1$ which is the $span\{\begin{bmatrix} 1-\lambda \\ \lambda \\\lambda\end{bmatrix}\}$.
But if I choose $\lambda =1$ und $\lambda =0$, I get the vectors $v_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\0\end{bmatrix} $ and $v_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix} $ which are also linearly independent and the $span\{v_1,v_2\}$ is exactly the space of the solution. But then the solutions set has dimension of 2?

Which part is wrong? Thank you if you could give me some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an homogeneous system. Therefore, the solution set (which is the one that you got) is not a vector space, and so it makes no sense to say that its dimension is $1$. Unless you meant its dimension as an *affine* space, in which case the fact that it has two linearly independent vectors does not contradict the fact that it's $1$-dimensional.